# How to configure WAMP and Smtp server

Tags: forms, smtp, wamp, contacts, configure

I have spent a significant time looking for an answer, and tried every solution without success :/

Basically I want to use wamp server to create contact form that will be sent to my mail address.

I have wamp running but for the life of me I can't figure out why I wouldn't receive the mails, I either get the 404 page when submitting the form, or lately "Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 553 sorry, that domain isn't in my list of allowed rcpthosts".

I am now looking for a solution that will at least send the form to my address, whether it's secured or not I just want to see an actual mail successfully sent.

Thanks !

edit: here is the code:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"                          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
<title> Contact Form</title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>

<div id="page-wrap">



    <div id="contact-area">

        <form method="post" action="contactengine.php">
            <label for="Name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" />


            <label for="Email">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" />

            <label for="Message">Message:</label><br />
                    <textarea name="Message" rows="20" cols="20" id="Message">                                   </textarea>

                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"                         class="submit-button" />
        </form>

        <div style="clear: both;"></div>



    </div>

</div>

    </body>

    </html>


    --then the contact engine--

    <?php

    $EmailFrom = "myadress@mail.com";
    $EmailTo = "myadress@mail.com";
    $Subject = "Nice & Simple Contact Form by CSS-Tricks";
    $Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
    $Tel = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Tel'])); 
    $Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
    $Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message'])); 

    // validation
    $validationOK=true;
    if (!$validationOK) {
      print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
      exit;
    }

    // prepare email body text
    $Body = "";
    $Body .= "Name: ";
    $Body .= $Name;
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "Tel: ";
    $Body .= $Tel;
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "Email: ";
    $Body .= $Email;
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "Message: ";
    $Body .= $Message;
    $Body .= "\n";

    // send email 
    $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

    // redirect to success page 
    if ($success){
      print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=contactthanks.php\">";
    }
    else{
      print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
    }
    ?>

    --then the thanks message--
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Strict//EN">

    <head>
        <title>A Nice & Simple Contact Form</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="page-wrap">

            <img src="images/title.gif" alt="A Nice & Simple Contact Form" />
            <p>By <a href="http://css-tricks.com">CSS-Tricks</a></p>


            <br /><br />


            <h1>Your message has been sent!</h1><br />

    <p><a href="index.html">Back to Contact Form</a></p>

        </div>

<script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/urchin.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
_uacct = "UA-68528-29";
urchinTracker();
</script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: You are going to have to show some actual code to get any help on this!

Comment: Yes sorry I added the code in my post, I just found it online to try to put my address with it.

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not come with a Mail Server so just calling mail() will work as far as php is concerned but the mail goes nowhere.

You either need to install a mail server or use something like the PHPMailer library to allow you to send SMTP mails via something like Yahoo or Google.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer ! I will try that and come back ASAP.

Comment: I managed to get PHPmailer working thanks ! I will try to implement it in my contact form now